# Leaflet and Web Coverage Service

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ogc

currently I am trying to use a `WCS` as an overlay for a leaflet map.
I already found https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas which is able to display raster data.
My Question is: Is there a way to just add a `WCS-URL` and tell leaflet which data to display? Probably without an additional leaflet plugin?
Or can someone tell me another way to visualize `WCS-Data` in a map with js?

Comment: A WCS exposes raw data, is there no WMS you could use instead?

Answer (score 0):

This Leaflet plugin will let you display WCS as a layer in Leaflet.

https://github.com/stuartmatthews/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer.WCS/blob/master/NonTiledLayer.WCS.js